# PHP Call abstract class method from another namespace

Tags: php, class, methods, abstract

i have class **OnboardingConversation**, where i call method **say** from namespace **BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation**

```
namespace PanObed\Conversations;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;

class OnboardingConversation extends Conversation{

      protected $name;
 
        public function __construct() {

        return $this->run();

        }

      public function run() {

        $this->say("Say hello");

      }
}
```

and there is class **BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation**

```
namespace BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations;

use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\Interfaces\ShouldQueue;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Attachments\Audio;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Attachments\Contact;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Attachments\File;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Attachments\Image;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Attachments\Location;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Attachments\Video;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\IncomingMessage;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Spatie\Macroable\Macroable;

abstract class Conversation
{

     use Macroable;

    /**
     * @var BotMan
     */
    protected $bot;

    public function say($message, $additionalParameters = [])
    {
        $this->bot->reply($message, $additionalParameters);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But there is a problem, when I call **new OnboardingConversation** i have this error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function reply() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\panobed\bot\vendor\botman\botman\src\Messages\Conversations\Conversation.php:205
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\panobed\bot\class\Conversations\OnboardingConversation.php(32): BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation-&gt;say('Test')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\panobed\bot\class\Conversations\OnboardingConversation.php(23): PanObed\Conversations\OnboardingConversation-&gt;run()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\panobed\bot\index.php(27): PanObed\Conversations\OnboardingConversation-&gt;__construct()
#3 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(BotMan\BotMan\BotMan))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\panobed\bot\vendor\botman\botman\src\BotMan.php(495): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\panobed\bot\vendor\botman\botman\src\BotMan.php(425): BotMan\BotMan\BotMan-&gt;callMatchingMessages()
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\panobed\bot\index.php(32): BotMan\BotMan\BotMan-&gt;listen()
#7 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\panobed\bot\vendor\botman\botman\src\Messages\Conversations\Conversation.php</b> on line <b>205</b><br />
```

If I do not use namespace **PanObed\Conversations**, code is OK. So can you someone tell me, what i am doing wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to set `$this->bot` property anywhere.

You should initialize it probably in `OnboardingConversation::__constructor`.
After you initialize `$this->bot` with correct object, your code should be able to call `$this->bot->reply(...)`